# how to pass xml to specific REST service as part of uri

Tags: c#, xml, rest, xml-serialization

I have to call a web service that has the following uri:

https://www.domain.com/accounts/clients/{clientId}/getdocuments

Can someone tell me how I'm suppose to pass xml to this? I know I could pass it as json and it would be straight forward but can't as everything in this project was done via xml.

It's a "GET" command and I'm using HttpWebRequest using c# and other methods are working fine but I'm struggling with this specific uri.

Should I just pass an 1234 when writing the stream? I somehow doubt it!

All I have in the documentation is this line, telling me that's the request

{clientId} -

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should pass just a client id, not an xml document, what is impossible using GET method

Comment: I wouldn't say *impossible*. Hard, limited in length etc.

Comment: @I4V Most of xml files have line breaks, which are illegal in query string. But your right, more than impossible it would be stupid to design such API.

Comment: when you *escape* the xml string for using in url, line breaks will be `%0d%0a`, so no problem. (`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xml)`).

Comment: I'm not trying the pass a xml document. Sorry if not clear on this! I'm just trying to figure out how to pass the parameter to the uri using xml. I'm just confused by the uri having this param between 2 (don't know what that's called!) sections of the uri. I have a login (..../security/login) function which has no param in its uri and I have no problem passing UID, PWD and API Key, etc... using xml format and writing to the request stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send your file using GET method, then you have to encode it in your request URI, which is not recommended in the RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3

Comment: Since I'm already logged in, though not visible, there is a token being sent with every request so seeing the clientid in the uri is not an issue here. I'm trying to understand how to handle this parameter {clientId} defined in the uri when using xml instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem! XML is not actually involved in it at all.

You just need to pass the parameter directly in the uri as part of the uri, so if you have:

https://www.domain.com/accounts/clients/{clientId}/getdocuments

and your clientId = a8v8s94244b89sf32 for example, when you call the HttpWebRequest, you will need to call the following uri:

https://www.domain.com/accounts/clients/a8v8s94244b89sf32/getdocuments

Hope this helps!